# Knockout.js - How to revert to previous value in a Dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

On my page, when a user changes a dropdown selection, I have to show a prompt *"Are you sure you want to continue?"*. If they click yes, then proceed with the new value else keep the old value in the dropdown.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of a "protected observable". You could extend this to display a prompt when a new value is submitted, then call .reset() or .commit().

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

ps. as a user I hate popup prompts. Perhaps having a confirm/reset button that shows up when the drop down changes would be better. Look at Ryan's jsFiddle sample.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the article. Its nice to know that such a thing exists. However, I am still not able to resolve my issue. What happens is - I have a subscription on the selectedItem of my dropdown which does some data fetching from the server via Ajax. Also, subscription fires first even before the change event. So, the values do not get reverted back. Can you possibly guide me how to resolve this. Much thanks!

Comment: @annantDev were you able to resolve this? I've got the same scenario. Have tried playing with valueHasMutated(), extenders, read/write observables. no luck yet.